# How can Chronic myeloid Leukaemic drugs reduce the production of the Philadelphia genotype?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, cell-biology, proteins, cancer

How can Chronic Myeloid Leukaemic drugs (Tyrosine kinase inhibitors, e.g. imatinib, etc.) that act by inhibiting bind of ATP to the active site of the BCR-ABL1 protein actually reduce the prevalence of the Philadelphia chromosome? (For example, optimal response to TKIs in 3 months would be Ph+ <35% and/or BCR-ABL1 <10%.) What I am actually asking is how a drug that targets the result of the oncogene (the BCR-ABL1 protein) can have an effect on the source (ie. genotype of the cells), as CML is a clonal haematopoietic stem cell disorder?

An example Reference paper: [Apperley JF. Chronic myeloid leukaemia. Lancet. 2015 Apr 11;385(9976):1447-59. doi: 10.1016/S0140-6736(13)62120-0. Epub 2014 Dec 5. PMID: 25484026.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0140673613621200?casa_token=uDbAQGUmObwAAAAA:J40xECHuhFOFm4-cimV3ZtcK-d15dGzQMkY3Wuxkvz5bSxSDe4V70q9XYlTrWm3bYWZNRwKNH2E)

Comment: Very interesting question! Could you cite a paper too? thanks

Comment: @EvanP Just added. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The key is that TKIs, such as Imatinib, are a therapy rather than a cure

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imatinib#Mechanism_of_action), Imatinib acts as a competitive inhibitor of the otherwise constitutively-active BCR-ABL fusion *protein*, rather than the fusion *gene*.  By binding the kinase domain, BCR-ABL is unable to phosphorylate downstream effectors that result in unchecked proliferation.  As long as a patient continues to take Imatinib, BCR-ABL activity should be blocked.

[image]

In the past few years (i.e, long after imatinib's discovery) there has been a lot of research into exactly *how* hematopoetic stem cells, which reside in the marrow and create leukemic blasts, work. Most HSCs remain in a [quiescent state](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2950323/), but it's not particularly well-known how frequently they turn over.  [Recent CML studies](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5842492/) have shown that after ~5 years, a large portion of CML patients can safely taper the the drug.  Presumably this is related to HSC turnover, but frankly as a leukemia molecular biologist rather than a physician, I'm not the best font of clinical knowledge.